# running linker in bare-metal arm example and linker can't find the loader file which exists

Tags: gcc, makefile, arm, bare-metal

I found a bare-metal example for a board different from mine so I will have to modify the loader script but for now I just want to be able to compile and link the example as it is.

I copied the arm-none-eabi cross-compiler to the directory just above c_blinky which is where the source files are. 
(I have a diagram of the directory structure on a page on my [website](http://www.hampleman.com/dev/bare-metal/bare-metal.aspx))

Here's the makefile:

```
ifeq ($(GNU_ARM),)
GNU_ARM = ../arm-none-eabi/bin
endif
CC    := $(GNU_ARM)/arm-none-eabi-gcc
CPP   := $(GNU_ARM)/arm-none-eabi-g++
ASM   := $(GNU_ARM)/arm-none-eabi-as
LINK  := $(GNU_ARM)/arm-none-eabi-gcc
BIN   := $(GNU_ARM)/arm-none-eabi-objcopy
RM    := rm -rf
MKDIR := mkdir
BLDDIR  = .
CCINC   = -I$(BLDDIR)
APP_DEP = $(BLDDIR)/bsp.h \
    $(BLDDIR)/arm_exc.h \
    $(BLDDIR)/isr.h
APP_NAME = blinky
ARM_CORE = arm7tdmi
ifeq (rel, $(CONF))       # Release configuration 
BINDIR = rel
CCFLAGS = -c -mcpu=$(ARM_CORE) -mthumb-interwork -Os \
-mlong-calls -ffunction-sections -Wall -DNDBEBUG -o$@
ASMFLAGS = -mcpu=$(ARM_CORE) -mthumb-interwork -o$@
LINKFLAGS = -T .\$(APP_NAME).ld -o $(BINDIR)\$(APP_NAME).elf \
    -Wl,-Map,$(BINDIR)\$(APP_NAME).map,--cref,--gc-sections
else                     # default Debug configuration 
BINDIR = dbg
CCFLAGS = -g -c -mcpu=$(ARM_CORE) -mthumb-interwork -O \
    -mlong-calls -ffunction-sections -Wall -o$@
ASMFLAGS = -g -mcpu=$(ARM_CORE) -mthumb-interwork -o$@
LINKFLAGS = -T .\$(APP_NAME).ld -o $(BINDIR)\$(APP_NAME).elf \
    -Wl,-Map,$(BINDIR)\$(APP_NAME).map,--cref,--gc-sections
endif
all: $(BINDIR)/$(APP_NAME).bin
$(BINDIR)/$(APP_NAME).bin : $(BINDIR)/$(APP_NAME).elf
    $(BIN) -O binary $(BINDIR)/$(APP_NAME).elf $(BINDIR)/$(APP_NAME).bin
$(BINDIR)/$(APP_NAME).elf : \
    ./$(APP_NAME).ld \
    $(BINDIR)/startup.o \
    $(BINDIR)/arm_exc.o \
    $(BINDIR)/low_level_init.o \
    $(BINDIR)/isr.o \
    $(BINDIR)/bsp.o \
    $(BINDIR)/blinky.o
    $(LINK) \
    $(BINDIR)/startup.o \
    $(BINDIR)/arm_exc.o \
    $(BINDIR)/low_level_init.o \
    $(BINDIR)/isr.o \
    $(BINDIR)/bsp.o \
    $(BINDIR)/blinky.o \
    $(LINKFLAGS)
$(BINDIR)/startup.o: $(BLDDIR)/startup.s
    $(ASM) $(ASMFLAGS) $<
$(BINDIR)/arm_exc.o: $(BLDDIR)/arm_exc.s
    $(ASM) $(ASMFLAGS) $<
# choose the ARM or THUMB compilation for each module...
$(BINDIR)/low_level_init.o: $(BLDDIR)/low_level_init.c $(APP_DEP)
    $(CC) -marm $(CCFLAGS) $(CCINC) $<
$(BINDIR)/isr.o: $(BLDDIR)/isr.c $(APP_DEP)
    $(CC) -marm $(CCFLAGS) $(CCINC) $<
$(BINDIR)/bsp.o: $(BLDDIR)/bsp.c $(APP_DEP)
    $(CC) -mthumb $(CCFLAGS) $(CCINC) $<
$(BINDIR)/blinky.o: $(BLDDIR)/blinky.c $(APP_DEP)
    $(CC) -mthumb $(CCFLAGS) $(CCINC) $<
```

I set GNU_ARM in the makefile to ../arm-none-eabi/bin and ran make and got the following error:
 (the file blinky.ld does exist in the source directory)

```
../arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc \
    dbg/startup.o \
    dbg/arm_exc.o \
    dbg/low_level_init.o \
    dbg/isr.o \
    dbg/bsp.o \
    dbg/blinky.o \
    -T .\blinky.ld -o dbg\blinky.elf -Wl,-Map,dbg\blinky.map,--cref,--gc-sections
/home/dan/dev/compile/bare-metal/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: cannot open linker script file     .blinky.ld: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [dbg/blinky.elf] Error 1
```

I thought the LINK assignment at the beginning should be:

```
LINK  := $(GNU_ARM)/arm-none-eabi-ld
```

and not

```
LINK  := $(GNU_ARM)/arm-none-eabi-gcc
```

and I got:

```
../arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi-ld \
    dbg/startup.o \
    dbg/arm_exc.o \
    dbg/low_level_init.o \
    dbg/isr.o \
    dbg/bsp.o \
    dbg/blinky.o \
    -T .\blinky.ld -o dbg\blinky.elf -Wl,-Map,dbg\blinky.map,--cref,--gc-sections
../arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi-ld: cannot open linker script file .blinky.ld: No such file or directory
make: *** [dbg/blinky.elf] Error 1
```

It looks like arm-none-eabi-gcc is calling collect2 in lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3 which in turn calls ld which is not in the main bin directory:

```
/home/dan/dev/compile/bare-metal/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld:
```

I tried making a symbolic link to arm-none-eabi-ld as ld and got the same error.

Comment: You would appear to have the wrong path separators in your `LINKFLAGS` - I have a feeling the linker's telling you the truth that you don't have a file named `.blinky.ld`, but you do have one named `blinky.ld` in the current directory, `./`.

Comment: they were using .\ instead of ./ - it was ported from DOS

Comment: Well, the fact that the rest of it is using UNIX-style paths and apparently works, and the `\` is being interpreted as an escape character, suggests pretty strongly that you're not running it on DOS, thus it needs fixing ;)